# Constraining question list with multiple tags

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

Please excuse this beginner's level question, and take pity if this is the wrong place to ask it. I am sure that this is something that is easy to do, but for the life of me, I can't seem to figure it out.

I am using Stack Overflow. One of the tabs on the default page is *Questions*, where I can see a list of all sorts of programming questions. Sadly, my time is not infinite, and I would like to constrain the listing somewhat.

Usually I would like to just see listings that have any of the tags in a group, like:

[xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode), [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c), [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx)

Although, occasionally, I want something that has more than one tag, like only articles that have both OSX and TCP.

I have found that I can go to the *Tags* tab off the page, and select one tag to constrain my list of questions, but so far I have not been able to get multiple tags.

Ideally I would like to be able to set a default set of constraints. I set up a list of favorites, but don't see how I can apply them to the questions.

Simple, right?

Comment: use search box: `[xcode] or [objective-c] or [osx] is:question` and then hit _Newest_.

Comment: thanx, that helps with the general question, but doesn't answer the longer term issue, how can i get the question list to appear filtered initially/automatically?

Comment: I guess this falls under feature-request.

Comment: Make a search, and bookmark the result.

Comment: There's the "Favorite tags" section in the right-hand bar.  Setting tags in there will highlight those questions with matching tags, making it easier to pick the ones that interest you out of the list.

Answer (score -1):

In the search-box, you can insert `[tag-name]` to search for a tag. You can include as many as you want. Also, use `+[tag-name]` to pay paticular attention to that tag, and `-[tag-name]` to exclude a tag from the results.