# Allow multiple tags to be chosen in "Tags"

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-search

This was partially addressed in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251719/constraining-question-list-with-multiple-tags) question, but I feel like it got lost amidst the user's more general question of how to filter by multiple tags in the first place.

I'm aware that you can search multiple tags in the Search bar by using `[Two] [RelatedTags]` and you can even exclude tags by using `- [dontLikeThisTag]`. However, I don't feel that this is particularly intuitive or well publicized/documented. I've been a member on this site for a year now, and I only just found this information, and, even then, by accident.

I think that the option to search/filter by multiple tags should be integrated into the "Tags" UI itself. It could allow you to add tags in the same manner you add them when you ask a question (in a single bar where you can just `Tab` to select another tag), or there could be narrowing options on the side akin to a shopping website where you can "refine the search", or something else entirely.

In addition to simply helping the user experience, I think it would encourage the practice of well-researching your topic before asking a question. Keyword searches are helpful, but tags often allow you to find answers to questions you can't think of the right keywords for.

Comment: So under or next to the tag search there would be another search field that says something like "Search questions with multiple tags"?

Comment: My specific thought was to make the field dynamic so that you could either just enter one (which would be suggested as you type like when you ask a question) and then search, or you could add more with the same process in the same form. Each tag would have the little blue highlighting and "x" option to make it clear you could use more than one.